# How to overcome cyclic dependency of IEnumerable without Service Locator or Lazy<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, service-locator

I have a dependency of `IEnumerable<ITransform>` which is used like this

```
class A
{
  public A(IEnumerable<ITransform> transforms) {...}
}
```

I have a bunch of `ITransform` implementations that I register from an assembly.

Now I need to create a new `ITransform` implementation which uses others `ITransform` implementations

```
class BTransform : ITransform
{
   public BTransform (IEnumerable<ITransform> transforms) {...}
}
```

That produces circular dependency. To resolve it I introduced `TranformFactory` which depends on `IServiceProvider` and resolve `IEnumerable<ITransform>` on demand.

```
class TransformFactory 
{
   IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   public TransformFactory (IServiceProvider serviceProvider) { _serviceProvider = serviceProvider; }

   public ITransform Create(string TransformName)
   {
       var transforms = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEnumerable<IComparisonCorrelationTransformation>));
       return transform.First(...);
   }
}
```

This factory obviously is Service Locator Anti-Pattern. But maybe this is a situation where it's applicable? Could someone give an advice on how to solve my problem without anti-patterns and other crude hacks?

Comment: Would you accept just filtering for `BTransform` in the registered `ITransform`? Sounds like the simplest solution

Comment: "That produces circular dependency" -- no it doesn't? This is a fairly normal approach. In pattern terms, this is a composite. A circular dependency would exist only if you passed an instance of `BTransform` to itself somehow, but that would need at least two instances, and an error in the configuration somewhere.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it creates circular dependency because `BTransform` registered as a part of `IEnumerable<ITransform>` which is injected into it

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is a circular dependency for the .NET DI system: " A circular dependency was detected for the service of type..." (an exception is thrown)

Comment: Alright, but that's a limitation of the DI framework, or (more probably) how it's invoked. I have little practical experience using Microsoft's stuff in this area, but if this cannot be overcome without having to change the type signature I'd consider that a serious shortcoming.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Do you mean not registering it as a part of `IEnumerable<ITransform>` transforms? That's not gonna be an option, because I need to use it as a part of this list in other places

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is a circular dependency. If `BTransform` is registered with the container as an `ITransform`, how can `BTransform` be instantiated when it depends on itself?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: an implicit assumption is made here (which is not made clear in the question) that an instance of `BTransform` can only be created by somehow instantiating every type implementing `ITransform`. But while that may well be what you end up getting with a default setup of your dependency injection framework, there is absolutely no requirement that this be the case. Indeed, without a DI framework you *can't* pass an object instance to its own constructor, so no (direct) dependency can arise in the first place. Hence my hope that this is fixable without contorting the type itself.

Comment: To put it another way: there are many ways of producing an `IEnumerable<ITransform>` instance. If no DI framework was used, filtering out a composite type (either explicitly or because it implements `ICompositeTransform` or somesuch) would be easy enough. It's only the "configuration by convention" part of a DI framework that would make it difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this with the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection framework. Look at the duplicate for some ideas